# xls downloaded from linux not the same as downloaded from windows

Tags: javascript, php, xml, xls

i´ve got a question about something very strange... Why is the xls file, which i create with php, not the same when i download it from a linux server as when i download it from a windows server?

With js i parse a html table, filter some columns out and push the table into a form and submit it to a php script. In the script i echo an xml file with the specific headers. When i do this on windows with xampp and download and open the file i get an message from excel that the content and filetype not match, but i can open it. When i download the same file (new generated file with same content) from a linux server i cant open the file - not even the message appears.

The filesize, content, encoding - All the same...

Why does this happen?

**EDIT**:
When i open the file (which i downloaded from linux) with notepad++, change a line, undo and save this, excel can open the file (with the message that the content and filetype not match).

Here's some code for your understanding:

JS-Part:

```
// var filename = string
// var this table = previously parsed html table
$('<form target="_blank" action="download.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="filename" value="' + encodeURIComponent(filename) + '" /><input type="hidden" name="data" value="' + encodeURIComponent(thisTable) + '" /></form>').appendTo($('body')).submit().remove();
```

PHP-Part:

```
<?php
 header('P3P: CP="NOI NID ADMa CAO PSA OUR IND UNI COM NAV"');
 header("Content-Type: application/ms-excel");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_REQUEST['filename'].".xls\";");
 echo "<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">";
 echo "<head>";
 echo "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
 echo "<xml>";
 echo "<x:ExcelWorkbook>";
 echo "<x:ExcelWorksheets>";
 echo "<x:ExcelWorksheet>";
 echo "<x:Name>".$_REQUEST['filename']."</x:Name>";
 echo "<x:WorksheetOptions>";
 echo "<x:Panes>";
 echo "</x:Panes>";
 echo "<x:PageSetup>";
 echo "<x:Layout x:Orientation=\"Landscape\"/>";
 echo "</x:PageSetup>";
 echo "</x:WorksheetOptions>";
 echo "</x:ExcelWorksheet>";
 echo "</x:ExcelWorksheets>";
 echo "</x:ExcelWorkbook>";
 echo "</xml>";
 echo "<![endif]-->";
 echo '<style type="text/css">td{mso-number-format:"#\,##0\.00";} @page {mso-page-orientation:landscape;}</style>';
 echo "</head>";
 echo "<body>";
 echo utf8_decode(urldecode($_REQUEST['data']));
 echo "</body>";
 echo "</html>";
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your not writing an xls file with that code

Comment: @Dagon: Maybe not a "real" xls file but a type of so excel can open and interpret it (when downloaded from windows server / xampp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be the file from Linux is "blocked" because the file has come from an unknown computer. If you look at the file's properties in Windows, at the bottom there may be a message about security and the ability to "unblock". Because you edited and saved the Linux file, Excel now thinks it is a safe file from your Windows computer and therefore not blocked.

Article https://superuser.com/questions/1103241/excel-no-longer-receive-the-option-to-open-files-in-a-different-format explains that a recent "patch" from Microsoft has introduced this restriction (Windows Update KB3115130 for Excel 2010 and Windows Update KB3115262 for Excel 2013), as well as the following options to help:

> **Option 1**
>
> - Control Panel > Internet Options
> - Security Tab > Trusted Sites
> - Add the site you are downloading from to the trusted site list
>
> ** You will need to re-download excel files once this change is made. Files previously downloaded when untrusted may still open blank **
>
> **Option 2**
>
> - Go into the properties of the file you have saved to your computer (right click it, then left click properties)
> - Click Unblock
> - Click Apply
> - Open the file
>
> **Option 3**
>
> - Open Excel Go to File Options
> - Click Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings
> - Go to Protected View. there are 3 options that show that were all clicked. Uncheck the first option that reads -- "Enable Protected View
>     for files originating from the Internet"
>
> **Option 4**
>
> - Open Excel Go to File Options
> - Click Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings
> - Go to File Block Settings
> - Uncheck Web Pages and Excel 2003 XML Spreadsheets
>
> **Option 5**
>
> - Uninstall the previously mentioned update that applies to your Office version

Comment: Thank you very much! The file was indeed blocked. I tryed option 2 and it worked for me!